# How do I split a row into two rows based on a column in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I need to split a row into two rows based on a column string.
Any idea what can be used for this?

```
data
----
BBB, R
AAA, RT
CCC, T
```

this is what I need to be returned from the select

```
AAA, R
AAA, T
CCC, T
BBB, R
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Or, what research did you do (perhaps on "how to split a string into individual characters in SQL Server") and what about it didn't you understand so that we can help explain it.

Comment: I disagree with the tag [tag:recursive-query] @GMB. There are more performant methods, and the OP makes no mention about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to put each character of the string on a new row. One option uses a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select col1, col2, 1 i from mytable
    union all
    select col1, col2, i + 1 from cte where i < len(col2) 
)
select col1, col2, substring(col2, i, 1) as new_col2 
from cte
order by col1
```

The recursive query enumerates the positions in the string, then the outer query extracts the corresponding characters.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0f550a12a9ef79dac37b1c25cc1f4f1)**:

```
col1 | col2 | new_col2
:--- | :--- | :-------
AAA  | RT   | R       
AAA  | RT   | T       
BBB  | R    | R       
CCC  | T    | T
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, a pretty straight forward approach is:

```
select v1.col1, v2.col2
from t cross apply
     (values (left(t.data, 3))) v1(col1) cross apply
     (values (substring(t.data, 6, 1)),
             (substring(t.data, 7, 1))
     ) v2(col2)
 where v.col2 <> '';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e983dbe065925bc690b16888ac7144df) is a db<>fiddle.